# no such file to load -- json (first request only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As the title suggests, I'm getting that error ONLY on the first request to the application.  Subsequent requests work fine.  This is occurring on several of the machines I'm running the application on.

I'm not using anything JSON related in this app (at least not that I'm aware of).

I should also point out that adding `gem 'json'` to the Gemfile makes the error "go away".  I'd be ok with this, but I'm afraid there's something more sinister at work here that will turn into a code-bomb later.

This is Rails 3.0.3 and Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: have you tried commenting out your gems one by one or checking their docs if any of them requires json?

Comment: some of your file may require json. try to install gem `sudo gem install json`.

Comment: @sayuj : yes,you are right.but don't forget to add json in gem file `gem 'json'` and `bundle install`. You can add this as an answer so that someone will be benefited

Answer (score 7):

Some of your files may require json. Try to install json with:

```
 sudo gem install json
```

Or

Add `gem 'json'` to Gemfile and do `bundle install`